# Frequency counting at two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make vigenere cipher attack. I have encrypted text with an unknown key length. I am solving algorith which finds the length of the key (i am spliting text on blocks where i am counting index of coincidence). 
For counting frequencies earlier i used hash map. but now i have 2 dimensional array, and after all my map is empty, help me to find my problem, thanks :) Afrer all i am getting smth like {};
here is my code:

```
public static String count_coincidence (char[][] text){
    int p=0;
    HashMap<Character,Double> map = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
    int a =(int)('а');
    char[] dictionary = new char[32];
    for(int x=0;x<dictionary.length;x++){
        dictionary[x]=((char)(a+x));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<text.length;j++){
            for(int l=0;l<text.length;l++){

                if(text[i][j]==dictionary[l]){
                    char c = text[i][j];
                    Double val = map.get(new Character(c));
                    if(val != null){
                        map.put(c, new Double( (val + 1) ) );
                    }
                    if(val==null){
                        map.put(c,1.0);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

    String d=map.toString();
    return d;
}
```

And after each iteraion inside loop , i should to save somewhere the value of map.

Comment: If the map is empty your code probably never enter in the if(text[i][j]==dictionary[l]) statement.
Did you check text.length is greater than 0?
If it is, then the if statement is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop indices are all wrong. You have:

```
for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<text.length;j++){
        for(int l=0;l<text.length;l++){
            if(text[i][j]==dictionary[l]){
```

You want:

```
for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<text[i].length;j++){
        for(int l=0;l<dictionary.length;l++){
            if(text[i][j]==dictionary[l]){
```

If your intention is to iterate over the entire contents of an array, you need to make sure your index goes up to the size of the array you are intending to iterate over.

- i in `text[i]` range is  `[0, text.length)`
- j in `text[i][j]` range is `[0, text[i].length)`
- l in `dictionary[l]` range is `[0, dictionary.length)`